# My regular expression isn't working in grep

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Here's the text of the file I'm working with:

```
(4 spaces)Hi, everyone

(1 tab)yes
```

When I run this command - `grep '^[[:space:]]+' myfile` - it doesn't print anything to stdout.

Why doesn't it match the whitespace in the file?

I'm using GNU grep version 2.9.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several different regular expression syntaxes.  The default for grep is called **basic** syntax in the grep documentation.

From man **grep(1)**:

```
In basic  regular  expressions the meta-characters
?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead
use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).
```

Therefore instead of `+` you should have typed `\+`:

```
grep '^[[:space:]]\+' FILE
```

If you need more power from your regular expressions, I also encourage you to take a look at Perl regular expression syntax.  They are generally considered the most expressive.  There is a C library called PCRE which emulates them, and grep links to it.  To use them (instead of basic syntax) you can use **grep -P**.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `-E`:

```
grep -E '^[[:space:]]+' FILE
```

This enables extended regex.  Without it you get BREs (basic regex) which have a more simplified syntax.  Alternatively you could run `egrep` instead with the same result.

Comment: This is misleading.  The questioner is not using any features that require extended syntax.  He simply needs to backslash the + sign as per basic syntax.

Comment: That is true -- didn't realize that it accepted character classes as such in BRE. Will update.

Answer (score 1):

I found you need to escape the `+`:

```
grep '^[[:space:]]\+' FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `grep -P '^\s+'` instead, provided you’re using GNU grep. It’s a lot easier to type, and has better regexes.